# How to load assets dynamicaly in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What is the proper way to load external assets in Unity3D Webplayer?

My example consists of an empty scene and a button. I have to load an external asset into the scene when user clicks a button. Than i should assign scripts etc, but the question is - i can create an empty object with script, but how to load an external asset into it?

External asset is the file stored on the remote PC, accessible by http or any other protocol.

Comment: "external" how.  Are you trying to load something from the user's local machine or are you trying to dynamically load an asset you already created and packaged w/ the player?

Comment: I need to load an asset stored on the remote machine, accessible by http or any other protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity has the WWW class for accessing data from certain protocols, most notably http like you said above.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html

If the object returns successfully you can access the data it downloaded. You can access the raw bytes it downloaded and treat the data however you need. Alternatively, you can access it as text or a texture if that is applicable in your situation.

Comment: Can i load 3D models this way too?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at AssetBundles:

https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/assetbundle-fundamentals

Once the bundle is stored somewhere remotely you can download it using `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload` and then instantiate specific objects from it.